# node cannot receive cyrilyc caracters on http response

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, node-modules

I am using this url to get a translation from google translate service. This works bon languages like spanish and english, also it works translating to a russian from another language. The proble comes when I try to obtain the translation from russian language to english or to spanish for example.

```
var sl = "ru";
var tl = "en";
var msg = "привет, как насчет"; // how are you (en) or hola que tal (es)

var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sl + "&tl=" + tl + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);

        https.get(url, (resp) => {

            resp.setEncoding('utf8');

            let data = '';

            // A chunk of data has been recieved.
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
            resp.on('end', () => {
                console.log("result google api: " + data);                
            });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            ...
        });
```

The output of this is (data object):

```
[[["РїСЂРёРІРµС ‚, РєР ° Рє РЅР ° СЃС ‡ РµС‚","РїСЂРёРІРµС‚, РєР°Рє РЅР°СЃС‡РµС‚",null,null,3]],null,"ru"]
```

The url used is:

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=es&dt=t&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82
```

Thus, if I use that url on chrome or firebox, the output is OK.

```
[[["hola que tal","привет, как насчет",null,null,3]],null,"ru"]
```

EDIT:

I am trying this and nothing:

```
var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ru&tl=es&dt=t&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82";
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        res.pipe(iconv.decodeStream("win1252")).collect((err, body) => {
            if (err) throw err;        
            console.log(body);
          })
    });
```

I tried "win1252", "win1251", "utf16", ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8` parameters in your request parameters and don't set resp encoding

```
let https = require('https')

var sl = "ru";
var tl = "en";
var msg = "привет, как насчет"; // how are you (en) or hola que tal (es)

var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sl + "&tl=" + tl + "&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);

https.get(url, (resp) => {

    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log("result google api: " + data);
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it was not encoding issue, is only about url parameters.

Comment: Your welcome, if this is your answer,  "mark as answer" can be helpful for others.